# I'm having issues saving lists to py

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, file

```
        chunk.append(int(x))
        if z == 30:
            z = 0
            write.writerow(chunk)
            chunk = []
```

so I'm able to get the list to save in lines of 30's but it saves like

```
0,0,0,39,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10,6,6,8,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,39,0,0

0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10,6,6,8,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,39,0,0

0,0,39,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,27,14,9,9,13,1,1,1,1,1,0,27,0,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,39,0,0
```

when I want it to save like

```
0,0,0,39,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10,6,6,8,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,39,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10,6,6,8,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,39,0,0
0,0,39,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,27,14,9,9,13,1,1,1,1,1,0,27,0,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,39,0,0
```

I'm sure the answer is probably super obvious and the block of code I wrote is probably really bad but I'm really new so any pointers on anything please let me know

Comment: You have extra blank lines between the rows or is something else different?  Are you absolutely sure that is the case?

Comment: This is the print statement of the list https://paste.pythondiscord.com/eyivutuqit.json I added print after write.writerow(chunk)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the newline character by opening the file and setting the `newline` property.

```py
with open("file.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)

    chunk.append(int(x))
        if z == 30:
            z = 0
            write.writerow(chunk)
            chunk = []
```